# Setting LoadStyleStrategy to ALL has no effect

Tags: java, css, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm setting the `LoadStyleStrategy` in my `web.xml` to `ALL`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Unfortunately this hasn't any effect. The styles are still injected into the RichFaces components.

What may I be doing wrong? How can I even check, if it's working?

---

It's neither working when setting it to `NONE`. Could that be because I'm in a JBoss Portal environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Known bug in JBoss Portlet Bridge](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PBR-63). Won't get fixed since version 1.0.0 is no longer supported.

**Solution**: Switching to version 2.1.0-FINAL. Was pretty easy.